# pwa not work on Android but only on Chrome

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Tried to write a PWA, here is the code:

```
var app = document.getElementById('ist');
var deferredPrompt;
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {deferredPrompt = e; document.getElementById('ist').innerHTML ='Installa l\'App'});
app.addEventListener('click', async () => {
if (deferredPrompt !== null) {deferredPrompt.prompt();
const{ outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
if (outcome === 'accepted') {deferredPrompt = null;}}});
```

I state that I have installed the manifest.json file and the sw.js file;
on a desktop, with Chrome or Edge, it works perfectly but on Android it doesn't work.
What can I do?

Nothing, I don't know why it doesn't work just where it should work??????